# Getting ConnectionRefusedError in postgresql with asyncpg

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg

I am getting a ConnectionRefusedError when trying to connect to my database with

```
async def create_db_pool():
    db = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="hyena", user="postgresql", password="mypwd")
    print("Connect to database")

asyncio.run(create_db_pool())
```

I have changed user postgres to postgresql

This is the full error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5432)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error in the database logs?

Comment: Where can I get the database logs?

Comment: Often, they are in the logs directory of the database data location, but the location is defined in postgresql.conf.